# How to get elements from autogenerated @XmlSeeAlso?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, cxf

I'm generating java classes from `wsdl` using `cxf / jaxb` and the configuration `<jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false">`, which gives me the advantage to directly get the elements by getters and setters from the xml, not having to instantiate a `JAXBElement` explicit every time.

One element I want to access is autogenrated as `@XmlSeeAlso`.

Problem: the autogenerated class does not contain any getter for this class! How can I at all receive the properties inside there if there's no getter created??

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Fare", propOrder = {
    "some",
    "props"
})
@XmlSeeAlso({
    AnySubType.class
})
@Generated
public class AutoGeneratedClass {
    //there is no getAnySubType() method!
    //only getters for some, props etc.
}
```

Where as:

```
@Generated
public class AnySubType
    extends AutoGeneratedClass 
{
```

Comment: You can extract it using reflection API. But why do you need this?

Comment: It's a subclass - why do you need a getter?

Comment: well somehow a few values that I need to get from the xml are inside hte `AnySubType`, but a getter for that type is missing so I cannot access them...

Comment: @membersound Wait a minute. A field is in there but you don't have a getter? Please post your schema. Looks like a JAXB bug I recently addressed. Is the field called something like `contentOverrideFor...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will attempt to address the points you raised:

> //there is no getAnySubType() method!

There wouldn't be.  It isn't common object-oriented practice to have a method on a super class that returns an instance of a specific subclass.

> well somehow a few values that I need to get from the xml are inside
>   hte AnySubType, but a getter for that type is missing so I cannot
>   access them...

You would need to cast the instance of `AutoGeneratedClass` to `AnySubType` to access the subclass methods.

Comment: Oh I didn't know this. Great, casting works as expected.